# Sitemap auto generation fails because I use 'base' tag

Tags: html, sitemap, base-url

I use the 'base' tag in html files of my website, in order to have more readable links.
The problem is that when I use an online sitemap generator, they are not using the base url that I provide to construct the links but the current address of every page. So the links are all wrong.

For example, in this page:

```
http://example.com/page/one/
```

if there is a link like that:

```
<a href='page/two/'>something</a>
```

then the result in sitemap file will be:

```
http://example.com/page/one/page/two/
```

As you can see it appends the link to the page address and not to the base url that I provide. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Have you tried other sitemap tools (A1 Sitemap Generator, GSiteCrawler, search Google for more alternatives etc.) and if still a problem contact the developer(s) of the tool(s) you tried? If the problem persist, what is your website address?

Comment: I have tried all the free online sitemap generators and some software too. All do the same thing. I don't know if I should contact all the developers of all this tools!

Comment: I will probably need to see the page source to help further :( If you are worried about writing it online (which I understand, I sometimes have the same problem) I suggest writing a developer or two